# MS Live API get Tasks

Tags: c#, outlook

I need get tasks from calendars. I read documentation from [Live Connect Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/live/) but all i find it's a events, contacts, calendars, mail, but i need a tasks. Anybody know anything about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/live/en-US/f8f8c01d-f198-42fd-8ede-d4506fa448d7/no-support-for-todostask?forum=messengerconnect

Apparently no its not, no word on when either.

Comment: I know about this. But few app make do this.

Comment: Could you let me know where you have seen this happen? I'd like to look too and try and work out.